# Tracking down the case of the missing keyboard caret

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

On certain windows in our application the keyboard caret disappears when we check in / checkout objects.  This makes the UI readonly or editable.

So if I am on a text field and it is editable, and I check it in the blinking caret disappears.  I check it back out and the caret is still gone.  Both before and after I can use Shift+Left arrow or right arrow to see that the control still has focus (a .NET textbox control).

The odd thing is that it seems to happen all controls on certain windows but works fine for all controls on other windows.

I know this is a little vague, but I'm just looking for ideas of what could possibly make the keyboard caret disappear like this. (or how to troubleshoot or debug this issue)

We don't have any Cursor.Hide calls, there is not any code that calls ShowCaret or HideCaret ( I looked and we have no code with the word "caret" it it anywhere.

I've checked on both the good and bad controls and done some debugging to see that the cursor is "IBeam", and I've put some calls to GetCaretPos and GetCaretBlinkTime in, but in both the good and bad cases the values seem reasonable.

Comment: What do you mean by checking in/out an object?

Comment: We basically have an "Edit" button (or you can press Ctrl+E - which I am doing to keep focus on the same control).  This makes all the controls editable or non-editable.  If you keep doing it you toggle between editable and non-editable.  We set all the controls Readonly (or not Readonly).

Comment: This looks like a problem with the DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl.  I've created an issue at: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q424339

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress has confirmed that this will be fixed in the next release and offered me a temporary build if I need one.  Excellent customer support.